# Web browsers: Killing Flash after it's started

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, flash

Lots of browsers have extensions to prevent Flash from running.

Is there a way (extensions perhaps?) to kill a Flash object after it's started? I'm particularly interested in Chrome, but other browsers are helpful too.

Comment: Are you simply asking if its possible, within the capabilities of a Chrome add-on, to kill Flash?

Answer (score 0):

To stop the chrome flash plugin after it has started you can press **SHIFT+ESC** to bring up the chrome task manager. From here you can click the "**Plugin: Shockwave Flash**" process and end it.

Alternatively you can go to **chrome://plugins** and disable Adobe Flash Player completely.

Comment: It seems that these options either allow me to kill the entire tab or the Flash plugin. Ideally I am looking for the ability to kill one Flash object which is currently running. (Similar to how Flashblocker plugins allows you to unblock/run one Flash object at a time).